# Align the textbox to the listview wpf

Tags: wpf, listview

[image]

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="CoinsBox" Margin="10,28,0,76"  Width="336"  >

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40"  >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"   VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"   />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleShort}"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"   HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"    VerticalAlignment="Top"   HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Volume}"   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

how to put two textboxes under each other ?

if `Orientation="Vertical"`

[image]

The last two columns should be next

Now

[image]

Its must be

[image]

Comment: Try changing the orientation to Vertical. You want HKN to be directly underneath and aligned with Hacken right?

Comment: @user2619824 updated the question. Immediately did not said that all I have 4 textbox, they have to go in a row of 2, sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested stackpanels like so. Then to control the space between the columns, put a margin in one of the internal stackpanels.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Haxen"/>
        <TextBlock Text="hxn"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="10000$"/>
        <TextBlock Text="40404040"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```